# Problems with installing bcmwl-kernel-source. ubuntu 13.10 on MacBook Pro

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I recently just got Ubuntu 13.10. I was messing around with the live version of it and my wifi was working fine. I decided to install it and when I go to set up the driver to hook up my wireless it has me authorize it by putting in my password. Then it start to download then it goes back to something like, "do not use this device".

I have tried installing :

> sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source

It starts to load and it gives me the option if I want to continue or not. I insert "Y". It then spits out:

> Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main dims all 2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4
>   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Err http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted bcmwl-kernel-source amd64 6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu.com
>   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Err http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main fakeroot amd64 1.20-1
>   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu4_all.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Failed to fetch http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb   Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   Failed to fetch http ://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.20-1_amd64.deb     Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
>   E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing

I spaced out some of the links because my rep is not high enough to put more than 2 but...
I have no idea what do do from there. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you connected to the internet at the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not connected to the internet hence why 'server could not be resolved'.  The problem is that the proprietary drivers you used on the live usb need to be downloaded in your fresh installation.

There are a few solutions that I came across when experiencing this on my mbp:

1. Establish a wired internet connection - this will allow you to download updates and select the broadcom driver.
2. Set up a new bluetooth connection to a mobile device and use the tethered connection to download the drivers and updates.
3. Download the packages and dependencies manually by booting from the live CD (or another computer) and copy them over to your disk.

Hope this helps.